# Php Mailer Attatchment Error

Tags: php

Mail is send without attachment but when i add Attachment mail is not sent here is the code

use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

//Load composer's autoloader
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

```
// Database connection
require __DIR__ . '/include/database.php';
$db = DB();

//this is our upload folder 
$upload_path = 'testimage/';

//response array 
$response = array(); 

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){

if(isset($_POST['Name']) and isset($_FILES['Photo']['name']) and isset($_POST['Email']) and isset($_POST['Location']) and isset($_POST['Facility'])){

 date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Calcutta');
 $t_date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');  

 $now = DateTime::createFromFormat('U.u', microtime(true));
 $new_name = $now->format('YmdHisu');    

 $name = $_POST['Name'];
 $email = $_POST['Email'];
 $facility= $_POST['Facility'];
 $location = $_POST['Location'];
 $fileinfo = pathinfo($_FILES['Photo']['name']);
 $extension = $fileinfo['extension'];
 $file_url = $upload_path . $new_name . '.' . $extension;
 $file_path = $upload_path . $new_name . '.'. $extension; 

      $full_path = "http://website.com/foldername/$file_path";

 try{
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['Photo']['tmp_name'],$file_path);

    $db = DB();
    $query = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO test_details(Name , Photo , Email, Facility, Location , Timestamp) VALUES (:name , :photo, :email , :facility, :location , :time)");
    $query->bindParam("name", $name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query->bindParam("photo", $file_path, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query->bindParam("email", $email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query->bindParam("facility", $facility, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query->bindParam("location", $location, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query->bindParam("time", $t_date, PDO::PARAM_STR);

    if ( $query->execute())
   {
     $mail = new PHPMailer(true);                              // Passing `true` enables exceptions
     try {
     $mail->SMTPDebug = 2;                                 // Enable verbose debug output
     $mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
     $mail->Host = 'mail.host.com';  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
     $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
     $mail->Username = 'xxxxxxx';                 // SMTP username
     $mail->Password = 'xxxx';                           // SMTP password
     $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                            // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
     $mail->Port = 587;                                    // TCP port to connect to
     $mail->setFrom('xxxxxxx', 'xxxxxxxx');
     $mail->addAddress($email);               // Name is optional





    $mail->AddAttachment("$full_path");




    if($mail->send()){
    echo 'Data Submit Successfully';
    }
  } 
    catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'Message could not be sent.';

      }
    }

        }catch(Exception $e){
            $response['error']=true;
            $response['message']=$e->getMessage();
        }       
        }else{
        echo "Error Occured";
    }
}
```

Mail is not send with attachment when i will send mail without attachment it will send but not send with attachment
error show could not access the file than file name

Comment: show your error

Comment: Could not access file: http://websitename.com/foldername/testimage/20171102074144453200.png
<br>
Message could not be sent.